# <s:checkbox not appearing correctly in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

The below checkbox is appearing on top of the checkbox label. Like so -

[image]

The label should be appearing beside the checkbox.

Here is the code im using -

```
<s:checkbox label="Visibilty - Everyone" name="checkboxField1" value="aBoolean" fieldValue="true"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: What does it look like when you do a "view source"? Could it be that the HTML situation and CSS rules are just causing a line break?

Comment: add the parameter "labelposition" with a value of "left" or "top" and see if either makes a difference... Since the value is appearing _under_ this is odd, I would suspect a CSS issue as Pointy does.

Comment: Im defining my form like so - <s:form action="eventSearchActionClass" theme="css_xhtml"> When I remove the reference to the theme "css_xhtml" the display works. I need to keep the theme though..

Comment: then customize the theme

Comment: @Bozho, should probably paste "customize the theme" into the answer box so the question can be resolved.

Comment: @Quaternion fine. Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize your struts theme by changing the `labelposition`. (the answer is accumulated from comments)